# How to copy Quartz scheduler jobs from one database to another database

Tags: c#, sql-server, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

I have an existing Quartz job in the quartz tables in the SQL server. I would like to copy them to another database. 
Is there any way to copy an existing Quartz job into another database?

Comment: why not do any normal backup restore process?

Comment: Cannot do it, I have a different group of jobs and I would like to move group by group

Comment: theres tools out there to help migrate data from one sql instance to another.

Comment: Like what? I tried many of them, but it didn't work and I end up having a broken binary data

Comment: I’m looking for answer to this question, I’m using .net 6 and quartz.net 3.5.0 version. I have explained what I want here on this GitHub link https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/discussions/2233

Answer (score 0):

Your either going to have to do this manually using data migration **or** you can use the API to serialize/deserialize all of the data you need. There is an already made utility:

**org.terracotta.quartz.collections.ToolkitDSHolder**

Use that to get all the scheduler data you need, then use the following to serialize and deserialize it:

**org.terracotta.quartz.collections.SerializationHelper**

Then have some custom logic to transform the data however you wish. Could make a quick GUI that shows all the data before serializing, lets you edit it in memory to get your desired data set, then serialize that and after deserialization you don't need to do any more data transformation, just call the needed methods to create whatever you want.

There's some serialization tests in the GitHub so I'm guessing this works for some pieces that you need at least, if not all of them.

Another thing you might want to try is using **XMLSchedulingDataProcessor**, it takes an IOStream and the documentation is vague, so I'm wondering if you use an output stream if it will write an xml file for you that you can then load with an input stream.

It looks like there's other things you can do too, like use a remote connection to load the Schedulers on one system and then do something with them remotely.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy an existing Quartz job to another database, you have a few options:

•  You can use a data migration tool or script to copy the records from the Quartz tables in one database to another. However, you need to be careful about the data integrity and consistency, as well as the compatibility of the driver delegate classes and the database schema.

•  You can use the Quartz API to serialize and deserialize the job data using the SerializationHelper class. This will allow you to export and import the job data as binary files, and then use the SchedulerFactory class to create a new scheduler with the imported data.

•  You can use the XMLSchedulingDataProcessor class to export and import the job data as XML files. This will allow you to modify the job data in a human-readable format, and then use the Scheduler.AddJob and Scheduler.ScheduleJob methods to create and schedule the jobs from the XML files.